# Does "begin work" sound natural?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context, uncountable-nouns

I came across a line in a book:

> The indigotin would be dissolved in vats of alkali to make a yellowish dye, indigo white. It was then ready for the dyers to **begin work.**

**Begin work** here sounds strange and sounds like headlinese, with *work* used as a mass noun. I thought **begin to work** would be more suitable. Is **begin work** here grammatical and unstilted/natural?

Also are *"begin work on"* and *"begin working on"* interchangeable?

To borrow an example from [Anne Bogart's book](https://books.google.com/books?id=yZiBAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT43&dq=%22begin%20work%20on%22&pg=PT43#v=onepage&q=%22begin%20work%20on%22&f=false)

> Every time I **begin work on** a new production I feel as though I am out of my league.

Can it be rewritten as

> Every time I **begin working on** a new production I feel as though I am out of my league.

Comment: It sounds perfectly natural to this native US English speaker.  It's using *work* as a noun.  If you say "begin *to* work", you're using *work* as a verb, in which case it implies "it was ready for the dyers to begin to work *the indigo white*" which is a little odd.

Comment: @stangdon - I think more generally you can say *"I begin X."* where *X* is a verb in noun form. For most verbs, this is the infinitive form. i.e. *"I begin swimming. I begin landing. I begin cooking."*. Work seems to be a special exception here, and in fact "Begin working." sounds odd to me, as "working" is not the noun form of the verb.

Comment: @Myridium  Yeah, that's weird.  I can't think of another example like "begin work" that isn't a gerund or infinitive, so I'm going to have to guess it's an *idiomatic expression* not bound by expected grammar rules.

Comment: @Myridium -  *swimming/landing/cooking* are gerund forms, though, not infinitive.  One certainly can say "working" as a noun form, although it means something a little different from "work", like "The working of the metal takes hours".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both are correct. No, it doesn't make any logical sense.

Take *play*. It seems identical to *work* in every respect—except for how it can be used.

Both of these parallel constructions are incorrect:

> Every time I **begin play on** baseball I feel as though I'm out of my league.
>   Every time I begin **playing on baseball** I feel as though I'm out of my league.

Instead, these are correct:

> Every time I begin **to play baseball** I feel as though I'm out of my league.
>   Every time I begin **playing baseball** I feel as though I'm out of my league.

And, at the same time, these, while perhaps not outright incorrect, sound odd and would normally be rephrased:

> Every time I begin **to work a new production** I feel as though I'm out of my league.
>   Every time I begin **working a new production** I feel as though I'm out of my league.

That these two words, that are identical in every other way, differ in this respect indicates to me a usage that goes beyond strict rules of grammar.

Answer (score 0):

For me I would say

> Every time I begin work**ing** on a new production I feel as though I am out of my league. 
> (use of **gerund**)

or

> Every time I begin **to** work on a new production I feel as though I am out of my league. 
> (use of **to-infinitive**)

or maybe

> Every time I begin **my** work on a new production I feel as though I am out of my league. 
> (use of work as a **noun**)

As for @JasonBassford's concern whether "on" is needed, I believe that the use of prepositions are based on the verbs immediately in front, (i.e. **play** and **work**) instead of "begin". This logic might be a bit strange, to me at least.

Mr Bassford is correct, we wouldn't normally say **" to play on"** something (when the something is the thing you *play with* or simply *play*), but **"to work on"** something is definitely far from rare, not to say whether it is possible or grammatically correct.

Hope this helps!